# Twig's `is not none` syntax

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

When overloading Symfony's form templates I've come across strange checks in `choice_widget_collapsed` in `form_div_layout.html.twig`.

```
{%- block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {%- if required and placeholder is none and not placeholder_in_choices and not multiple and (attr.size is not defined or attr.size <= 1) -%}
        {% set required = false %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {%- if placeholder is not none -%}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ placeholder != '' ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ? placeholder : placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain)) }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </select>
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed -%}
```

What's the meaning of `if placeholder is not none`? I haven't encountered such syntax in Twig documentation, and googling it I've found only code copied from around the same file with no explanation.

I'm curious, why not `is not null`, `is not empty`, `is defined`? Where is `none` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test `none` is just an alias for the test `null` as seen in the [core extension](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php) of `Twig`:

```
public function getTests()
{
    return array(
        new Twig_Test('even', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Even')),
        new Twig_Test('odd', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Odd')),
        new Twig_Test('defined', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Defined')),
        new Twig_Test('same as', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Sameas')),
        new Twig_Test('none', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Null')),
        new Twig_Test('null', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Null')),
        new Twig_Test('divisible by', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Divisibleby')),
        new Twig_Test('constant', null, array('node_class' => 'Twig_Node_Expression_Test_Constant')),
        new Twig_Test('empty', 'twig_test_empty'),
        new Twig_Test('iterable', 'twig_test_iterable'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Twig Null docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/null.html)
`none` is an alias for `null` in Twig syntax.